# How do I join two different tables?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a two tables **customer** and **customer_pro** where **customer** table has customerID that is auto incremented  and **customer_pro** table has cus_billId that is also auto incremented.

Both the tables has different fields like 
**customer** = **customerID**,**name**,**amount**,**updAmount**
 **customer_pro**= **cus_billID**,**customerID**, **month**,**year**....

I want to print all the info from  **customer_pro** according to current cus_billID and also **amount** and **updAmount** from customer table according to 
selected **customerID**

What commands do I use to get the desired result?

Sample Input of Html Form of **customer_pro** like

```
Select customerID ........(**All **customerID** from customer Table)
Select Month      ........
select Year       ........
```

submit

When user press **submit** button then all info will inset in **customer_pro** table 
and also display those info according to current **cus_billID** that is auto incremented and display  **amount** and **updAmount** from customer table according to 
selected html form  **customerID**

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Then add a sample query that uses the keyword `JOIN`.  You'll probably get it right.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**INNER JOIN** is used to join two tables having a primary key and foreign key
Your query would be like:`$sql =  "SELECT  * FROM customer_pro INNER JOIN customer ON customer_pro.customerID = customer.customerID";`
Then you will have to execute the sql query using

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sql;)
```

After that create a table and use

```
while(mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
your table fields here
}
```

Comment: You need to store the row in a variable: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { // .... }`. (The `MYSQLI_ASSOC` is to fetch the columns as associative arrays).

Comment: But is show all customer_pro info I want to print current cus_billID info and also 2 field from customer table **amount** and **updAmount**

Comment: @Md.AbuZaman - The above is an example. Adapt it to fit your needs. (like join the correct tables and add a `WHERE` clause, etc.

Comment: And I am using mySql

Comment: @Md.AbuZaman - You should use mysqli or pdo. The `mysql_*`-functions are insecure and have been deprecated for several years and totally removed in PHP7.0